# Activating snapshot to start a BPM 8.6 process

Tags: business-process-management, ibm-bpm

When I try to start the process in BPM on rest I get an error:

```
Result:
{
status: "error",
Data:
{
status:  "error",
exceptionType: "com.ibm.bpm.wle.api.CannotStartBPDWrongStateException",
errorNumber:  "CWTBG0586E",
errorMessage:  "CWTBG0586E: Cannot start BPD because the snapshot or BPD is in the wrong state.",
errorMessageParameters: null,
responses:  null,
errorData:  null
}
```

}

Then I do everything as described in the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD1_BHFHP4Y&list=PL7D328AAEB82FE141&index=9

But in my rest it does not work and the error is the same.
The status snapshot remains active.

[image]

version BPM - 8.6.

Comment: Please share the REST API call you are making as well as showing that the user making the rest call also sees the BPD in the exposed process call.  This will help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I call this  rest: https://{host}:{port}/rest/bpm/wle/v1/process?action=start&bpdId=25.637e0355-f787-4bfa-953d-26bbbd939e5a&snapshotId=2064.514a322e-c8cc-4e18-b1a2-7cdc4fbc6f65&parts=all%7Cheader%7Cdata%7CexecutionTree

Comment: And that snapshot ID appears for the user you are using when you request the exposed items list?

Comment: Yes, its right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by iterating through the input parameters. To be able to start a task, I had to exclude from the request "snapshotId" and add "processAppId".
After that, I received an answer of 200 and the task started.
Version IBM Bussiness Process Manager Server 8.6.0.0 CF2018.03

Comment: If that worked it means that the snapshot was not activated.  When you make the REST call and don't provide a snapshotID it runs on the default snapshot.  In the process center that will be "tip".  On a process server it will be a specific snapshot.  I believe this means that the BPD wasn't showing as exposed in the exposure call.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for you answear. It is very impotant to me. But I dont` will agree with approval "not activaited". I provided this condition and described it in my question and added a screenshot.

Comment: You showed that there is an active snapshot.  We'd need the ReST exposure output to confirm that the Snapshot GUID you used is the snapshot you show in your screen shot.